# Linguagem C, exercício de matriz

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{   

    int matriz[5][5];
    int i, j, posicao=0;

    int maior = matriz[0][0];
    int menor = matriz[0][0];
    int posicaoI=0, posicaoJ=0, posicaoi=0, posicaoj=0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
        for(j=0; j < 5; j++){
            matriz[i][j]=rand()%101;
    }
    }

    for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
        for(j=0; j < 5; j++){
                if(matriz[i][j] > maior){
                    maior = matriz[i][j];
                    posicaoI = i;
                    posicaoJ = j;
                }
                if(matriz[i][j] < menor){
                    menor = matriz[i][j];
                    posicaoi = i;
                    posicaoj = j;
                }
            printf("(%d,%d) %d\n", i, j, matriz[i][j]);
    }
    }
            printf("Posicao (%d:%d), o maior valor é %d\n", posicaoI, posicaoJ, maior);
            printf("Posicao (%d:%d), o menor valor é %d\n", posicaoi, posicaoj, menor);
}
```

O maior valor gerado está funcionando normal, mas o menor valor ta dando resultado 0, posição (0:0).

Comment: Substitua maior por matriz[poscaoI][posicaoJ] e menor por matriz[posicaoi][posicaoj] e remova maior e menor e suas atribuições.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, pelo que vi, você está fazendo:

```
int matriz[5][5];   
int maior = matriz[0][0];
int menor = matriz[0][0];
```

Ou seja, você está atribuindo um valor a maior e menor que pode ser lixo de memória. Eventualmente, o lixo armazenado na variável maior pode ser maior que os valores da matriz e o mesmo para o mínimo. Experimente trocar para:

```
int maior = 0;
int menor = 99999999;
```

Acho que assim dará certo.

Comment: Também eu geralmente faço o uso do `memset` para setar uma array. É uma função muito útil e muito rápida, performance excelente. Neste caso seria `memset(&matriz, 0, sizeof matriz);`. Lembrando que faço uso do `sizeof matriz` pois não é um ponteiro, ou seja, ele irá usar o tamanho correto.